# White screen after splash image before home page loads

Tags: android, typescript, ionic2, splash-screen

On android device splash screen with `splash.png` from resources  loads with loading animation, then appears white screen for longer then splash screen, before home.page loaded. How can I avoid this, my `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

As attempt, I have tried guide from belove, it works as it is, but also show white screen after animated loading, before page load:

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/51/How-to-Make-an-Animated-Ionic-Splash-Page-with-HTML-&-CSS

Answer (score 0):

Take a look two guides how to implement splash on android:
https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565

and
https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154

Answer (score 0):

I wad also facing the same issue by adding these lines in the **config.xml** my problem was solved.

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

Hope it helps.